# dojo dijit.Dialog destroy underlay error

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog

I have a class that extends dijit.Dialog but only to set default functionality and buttons for my site. When clicking the dialog's cancel button the following code is run:

```
    this.actionDialog.destroyRecursive();
    this.actionDialog.destroy();
```

nb `this.actionDialog = dijit.Dialog`

Sometimes (not always) the following error gets thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined
DialogUnderlay.xd.js:8
```

Which causes following dialogs to incorrectly display. I am using 1.5 from Google API's. Am I missing something with the underlay code?

*Error thrown after Ken's answer:*

```
exception in animation handler for: onEnd
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Both from `dojo.xd.js:14`. But the code still works properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what the problem is, other than for some reason `dijit.DialogUnderlay` code is getting confused.  FWIW, this doesn't happen in Dojo 1.6.

While I was poking at some potential solutions, I seemed to accidentally find out that avoiding this problem is perhaps as easy as calling `hide()` on the dialog immediately before destroying it, e.g.:

```
this.actionDialog.hide();
this.actionDialog.destroyRecursive();
```

Alternatively, you might be interested in hiding the dialog, then destroying it once the hide animation finishes.

Here's how you can do it on Dojo 1.5 and earlier (tested 1.3+):

```
dlg.connect(dlg._fadeOut, 'onEnd', function() {
    this.destroyRecursive();
});
dlg.hide();
```

In 1.6, the fadeOut animation is no longer exposed on the instance (granted, it was technically private earlier anyway), but `onHide` now triggers once the animation ends (whereas before it triggered as soon as it began).  Unfortunately a setTimeout is needed to get around an error that occurs due to other code in the branch calling `onHide`, which assumes that something still exists on the instance which won't after we've destroyed it (see [#12436](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12436)).

```
dlg.connect(dlg, 'onHide', function() {
    setTimeout(function() { dlg.destroyRecursive(); }, 0);
});
dlg.hide();
```

See it in action on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3MNRu/1/  (See [the initial version](http://jsfiddle.net/3MNRu/) for the original error in the question)

Comment: Thanks very much, my code always throws an error (see updated post) when run, but it seems to work properly anyway.

Comment: Huh.  That's happening if you connect to onEnd?  Odd.  There's certainly a reference to `this.domNode.style` in the `onEnd` callback on the animation, but that code should be getting executed before any functions you connected to it.  I suppose you could try the `setTimeout` trick even on the 1.5 approach to see if that helps.  Out of curiosity, what browser is this on?

Comment: I'm testing on Chrome. I'll create a fiddle tomorrow to see if I can fix it at a more basic level and upload it. Thanks again

Comment: The problem was an event attached to the onCancel function calling hide() again.

Answer (score 2):

The *dialog.hide()* method returns a *Deferred*, your code can be something more readable like this:

```
var dialog = this.actionDialog;
dialog.hide().then(function(){ dialog.destroyRecursive(); });
```

Be careful not to do this:

```
this.actionDialog.hide().then(function(){ this.actionDialog.destroyRecursive(); });
```

At the context of **then** *this* has another meaning!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call destroyRecursive()

The second destroy command is what is probably causing the error, and the error probably is causing the issues with other dialogs.

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.3/dijit/_Widget/destroyRecursive

**destroyRecursive**

Destroy **this widget** and it's descendants. This is the generic "destructor" function that all widget users should call to cleanly discard with a widget. Once a widget is destroyed, it's removed from the manager object.

Comment: Good advice, but that's not what's causing the problem - I mocked it up with only a `destroyRecursive` call.  http://jsfiddle.net/3MNRu/ (click show, click destroy, click show, click destroy, boom)

Comment: Oh well, it was worth a shot. I really hate these types of errors with Dojo, they can be very hard to track down. It's a great framework and I love working with it, but these mystery errors where you need to do one tiny thing differently drive me absolutely crazy when I have them. Ken's solution looks interesting though, that may do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the IE8 error : `'this.focusNode.form' is null or not an object`. I found this was the result of the `dialog.hide()` returning a deferred. I wrote my own `_closeDialog` which eliminated the IE error.

```
_closeDialog : function(cntxt){
        cntxt.popup.hide().then(
        function(){
            cntxt.popup.destroyRecursive(false);
            cntxt.popup.destroy(false);
            cntxt.destroyRecursive(false);
            cntxt.destroy(false);
        });
    },
```